# several minor issues intsalling Fedora 24 to an external USB drive

Tags: linux, fedora, grub, uefi

Most of my computers are UEFI, so I had the idea of, instead of dual-booting each one, installing Fedora 24 to a removable USB hard-drive, and having one Fedora installation that I could use on any UEFI computer I wanted.
I did a little research, and it looks like this is actually pretty easy with UEFI, since basically every UEFI system is 64-bit, and supports booting from USB, and uses UUID instead of drive-number.  So I just went ahead an installed Feodra 24 to a removable usb drive like normal, and so far it's worked fine.  I just have a couple minor issues.

1. Since I will pretty much always be selecting my OS using the UEFI boot menu, and since I'll carry this drive between different computers, I want to disable OS probing during grub updates, and if possible, disable the grub menu all-together.  I've done the former (disabling os-probing) with `chmod a-x /etc/grub.d/30_os-probe`.  Will that work, or will there be Consequences?  And, how can I disable the boot menu in a way that will stick?
2. Since this drive will have to boot on different systems, I'd like to basically get every driver that would ever conceivably be necessary during boot into initrd -- at a minimum, every USB and GPU chipset in my current kernel.  Is there a way to do that (that would stick)?
3. It'd probably be nice if I didn't change the system time.  Is there a way to tell Fedora not to change the system clock when it updates the time?
4. The first partition is an NTFS partition.  This is both so Windows has something it can mangle other than the Fat32 file-system in the UEFI boot partition, and in the hopes that it would work as a swap-space (so I could also use this as a removable drive on Windows systems).  When I plug in the drive on Windows, nothing happens; it doesn't seem to see the NTFS partition.  I think the partition is fine, I can read it from the Linux boot at least; any clue as to why that wouldn't work?  (I might have the partition type set wrong; right now it's "Microsoft basic data", any clue what it should be?)

Thanks much

Comment: Please ask these as separate questions. Since this is a Q&A site rather than a discussion forum, that's preferred. Thanks.

Comment: Fedora 24 is still unreleased and in testing. If you find some problem, feel free to fill a bug or get in touch with developers or Fedora QA to get it resolved, before the final version lands.